# Get path of binary file within a JAR file

Tags: java, c++, jar

I have a jar file when unzipped looks like the following:

```
models/
com/
com/github/
com/github/
com/github/test/linux-x86_64/
com/github/test/config/
models/model.bin   
com/github/test/Test.class
```

In the Test class, I'm using the path of `model.bin` inside the getResults method like so:

```
public class Test {

      public List<Label> getResults(String text, int k) {

        // Load model from file
        loadModel("models/model.bin");

        // Do label prediction
        return results(text, k);
    }

}
```

The loadModel method above is actually c++ method that looks like this. I am writing a Java Wrapper around a c++ library:

```
void Testtext::loadModel(const std::string& filename) {

  std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
  if (!ifs.is_open()) {
    throw std::invalid_argument(filename + " cannot be opened for loading!");
  }
  if (!checkModel(ifs)) {
    throw std::invalid_argument(filename + " has wrong file format!");
  }
  loadModel(ifs);
  ifs.close();
}
```

Currently, when I run this from an IDE, I get an error that says the `model.bin` file cannot be found. How do I determine the path of the `model.bin` within a jar file?

Comment: Could you also add implementation of `loadModel()`? How its expecting the file path? Does it expect absolute file path or class path resource?

Comment: I've updated with more info on `loadModel`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like whatever `loadModel` is (it is not part of standard java, so you'd have to elaborate) requires an actual file. Which your `model.bin` resource isn't (it's an entry in a jar).

Check if `loadModel` has an `InputStream` based method. It really should; if it doesn't, whatever library this is, does not follow java conventions, and is probably badly written.

If it does:

```
try (InputStream in = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/models/model.bin")) {
    loadModel(in);
}
```

will do the trick.

If it doesn't, oh boy. Either fix loadModel yourself, ask its authors to fix it, or if you must work around it, your only option is to copy the resource into an actual file, presumably in a temp dir, and then use that temporary file. This isn't pretty.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run your suggestion: "incompatible types: java.io.InputStream cannot be converted to java.lang.String"

Comment: See the comment on 'if it doesn't, whatever...'